# Need to Transpose Columns via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have been googling all morning trying to figure out how to transpose my data via SQL, but I am just not getting it.  I have a table of data that I need to transpose the columns.

My original table looks like this:

[image]
(Column Names are in the top row)

I want to transpose the columns so my results are as follows:

[image]

Could someone please assist me with the correct code to use to get the results I need?  I can't just transpose via Excel because the data is dynamic.

EDIT:
I tried this code:

```
SELECT [Gift Level], Goal
FROM
(   SELECT * FROM GiftPyramidDollars)
AS Result
Unpivot
(Goal for [Gift Level] in ([< $25,000], [$25,000], [$50,000], [$100,000], [$200,000], [$250,000], [$500,000], [$1,000,000], [$2,500,000], [$5,000,000], [$10,000,000])
)
AS UnPvt
```

But it did not separate the results into two columns.  This is what I get:

```
Gift Level      Goal
< $25,000   0.00
$25,000         0.00
$50,000         0.00
$100,000    8000000.00
$200,000    10000000.00
$250,000    6250000.00
$500,000    12500000.00
$1,000,000  30000000.00
$2,500,000  12500000.00
$5,000,000  10000000.00
$10,000,000 10000000.00
< $25,000   58126.67
$25,000         260687.75
$50,000         394300.00
$100,000    352233.61
$200,000    800000.00
$250,000    2110000.00
$500,000    4603423.93
$1,000,000  11500000.00
$2,500,000  0.00
$5,000,000  5000000.00
$10,000,000 0.00
```

Comment: you want to UNPIVOT.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I've read about UNPIVOT this morning too, and tried it, but can't get the code figured out.

Comment: I have posted a [blog entry on pivot](https://hiflitetm.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/pivot/). It has some simple examples that might match your situation. Syntax might be specific to oracle SQL. Note that other posters are right: you intend to do an `unpivot`.

Comment: Please can you add the column names of your SQL data table to the question?

Comment: The column names are in the top row of the data.  Alternatively, they are Campaign, '< $25,000', '$25,000', '$50,000', '$100,000', '$200,000', '$250,000', '$500,000', '$1,000,000', '$2,500,000', '$5,000,000', and '$10,000,000'.

Comment: I've edited my question best I can; How can I get it off hold so someone can assist me?

Comment: Also, which version of SQL are you using - SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL...?

Comment: I am using SLQ Server.

Comment: Change your top level SELECT to `SELECT UnPvt.[Gift Level], [$ Goal] = MAX(CASE UnPvt.Campaign WHEN '$ Goal' THEN UnPvt.Goal END), [$ Raised to Date] = MAX(CASE UnPvt.Campaign WHEN '$ Raised to Date' THEN UnPvt.Goal END)` and tack `GROUP BY UnPvt.[Gift Level]` on the end.

Comment: Kittoes, thank you!  That worked!  I am very appreciative of your assistance.  -Tracey

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.[Gift Level]
     , [$ Goal] = MAX(CASE B.Campaign WHEN '$ Goal' THEN B.Goal END)
     , [$ Raised to Date] = MAX(CASE B.Campaign WHEN '$ Raised to Date' THEN B.Goal END)
FROM GiftPyramidDollars A
UNPIVOT(A.Goal FOR [Gift Level] IN (
    [< $25,000]
  , [$25,000]
  , [$50,000]
  , [$100,000]
  , [$200,000]
  , [$250,000]
  , [$500,000]
  , [$1,000,000]
  , [$2,500,000]
  , [$5,000,000]
  , [$10,000,000])
) B
GROUP BY B.[Gift Level]
```